# POST http://localhost:3000/api/sendMail 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, http-proxy-middleware

I am using http-proxy-middleware to send my form data from React front end to Express server,
but `http-proxy-middleware` doesn't seem to work.
It should proxy to `localhost://5000`.
Instead throws an error:

> POST http://localhost:3000/api/sendMail 404 (Not Found) .

front end code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class EmailForm extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    email: ""
  };

  handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
      name: this.state.name,
      email: this.state.email
    };
    console.log(data);

    axios.post("/api/sendMail", data);
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container mt-3">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <h4 className="grey-text text-darken-3">Send Email</h4>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="email">Name</label>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="text"
              id="name"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="email"
              id="email"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <button className="btn btn-danger">SendMeEmail</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default EmailForm;
```

setupProxy.js:

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy("/api", { target: "http://localhost:5000/" }));
};
```

Server.js :

```
app.post("/api/sendMail", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

Comment: You're using React right? Your react run on port: 3000 right and than, your express server run on port???

Comment: server on port 5000 and I am using concurrently

Comment: If your server running on port `5000`, than why you're using `3000` here:  `http://localhost:3000/api/sendMail`? I'ts must using `5000`, then it's will looks like this: ` http://localhost:5000/api/sendMail `

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to package.json (of react project)

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```